# Can somebody help to fix this problem? im realy tired of trying

Tags: django

> The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.

```
class EmailVerificationView(TitleMixin, TemplateView):
  title = 'Store - Подтверждение электронной почты'
  template_name = 'users/email_verification.html'

  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      code = kwargs['code']
      user = User.objects.filter(email=kwargs['email'])
      email_verifications = EmailVerification.objects.filter(user=user, code=code)
    if email_verifications.exists() and not email_verifications.first().is_expired():
        user.is_verified_email = True
        user.save()
        return super(EmailVerificationView, self).get(request, args, **kwargs)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

I already changed *get* to *filter*.
Before i had *get* in *user* there was issue "get() returned more than one user -- it returned"

Im trying to send email to verify acc.

models

```
class User(AbstractUser):
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='users_image', null=True, blank=True)
is_verified_email = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class EmailVerification(models.Model):
code = models.UUIDField(unique=True)
user = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
expiration = models.DateTimeField()

def __str__(self):
    return f'EmailVerification object for {self.user.email}'

def send_verification_email(self):
    link = reverse('users:email_verification', kwargs={'email': self.user.email, 'code': self.code})
    verification_link = f'{settings.DOMAIN_NAME}{link}'
    subject = f'Подтверждение учётной записи для {self.user.username}'
    message = 'Для подтвержденияч учетной записи для {} перейдите по ссылке: {}'.format(
        self.user.email,
        verification_link)
    send_mail(
        subject=subject,
        message=message,
        from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
        recipient_list=[self.user.email],
        fail_silently=False,
    )
def is_expired(self):
    return True if now() >= self.expiration else False
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code

Comment: Idk, i hope somebody can understand it

Comment: Can you please share the relevant model(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should *not* use a `.filter()` for the user, since that will return a `QuerySet` of users, not a single one.

```
from django.db.models.functions import Now


class EmailVerificationView(TitleMixin, TemplateView):
    title = 'Store - Подтверждение электронной почты'
    template_name = 'users/email_verification.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        code = kwargs['code']
        user = get_object_or_404(User, email=kwargs['email'])
        email_verification = EmailVerification.objects.filter(
            user=user, code=kwargs['code'], expiration__lte=Now()
        ).first()
        if email_verifications is not None:
            user.is_verified_email = True
            user.save(update_fields=('is_email_verified',))
            email_verification.delete()
            return super().get(request, args, **kwargs)
        else:
            # TODO: show warning, or something else?
            return redirect('index')
```

You should also make sure that the email addresses are *unique*, so that no two (or more) `User`s can have the same `email` address, so:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='users_image', null=True, blank=True)
    is_verified_email = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    email = models.EmailField('email address', blank=True, unique=True)
```

and thus make sure that the database table for this model indeed does *not* have any two `User`s with the same email address.

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

---

> **Note**: You can make use of [**`redirect(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) instead
> of first calling [**`reverse(…)`** <sup>[Django]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.reverse) and
> then wrap it in a [**`HttpResponseRedirect`** object <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect).
> The `redirect(…)` function does not only offer a more convenient signature to do this, it also for example will use the
> [**`.get_absolute_url()`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_absolute_url)
> if you pass it a model object.